# Load app.config dynamically when loading a DLL

Tags: c#, dll

My `DLL` is being loaded by another exe. The `DLL` uses libraries hosted on `Nuget` for example `Autofac, Autofac.WebApi2.`

My app.config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

When loading my DLL I get the following error message

```
 "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={token}' or one of its dependencies..."
```

The app.config is also deployed to the same directory as the `exe` named `{mydll.dll.config}`. How can I load this config dynamically so it makes use of the assembly bindings?

Comment: The `app.config` of DLL files is, at best, hints at what you should place in the EXEs app.config (or web.config). It's not used. The fact that some of the VS tooling will create an app.config file for DLLs is just part of the cruel joke.

Comment: Can I manually add an exe.config? Then load the exe.config from the dll?